# Google Cloud Connection Server and smack

Tags: java, smack, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get a java server set up for communicating to Google's Cloud Connection Server using the smack library.  I have set up an app ID and API key through Google APIs and am trying to use the following code:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;

public class CloudMessager {

public CloudMessager(){
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("gcm.googleapis.com", 5235);
    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

    Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    // Connect to the server
    try {
        connection.connect();

        connection.login("SENDERID@gcm.googleapis.com", "APIKEY");

        PacketListener myListener = new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

            }
        };

        // Register the listener.
        connection.addPacketListener(myListener,null);

    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
SASL authentication PLAIN failed: text: 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:342)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:221)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:366)
at org.umptyfratz.strongbox.CloudMessager.<init>(CloudMessager.java:25)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss to figure out where to go from here.  Has anyone else successfully connected to CCS using the Java smack library?

Comment: I have the same problem :( Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Benny- Not yet.  I'm going to try to find a proper Google contact to see if they can tell me what's going on.

Comment: Did you come any further - I have exact the same message. BTW: Are you sure that the username is SENDERID@gcm.googleapis.com and not just SENDERID?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - SENDERID@gcm.googleapis.com is definitive right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to debug the connection with this option:

```
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
```

This'll open a new window with the data sent and received.

If you find something like "Project SENDERID not whitelisted." you have to register your project [here](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/).

(This is in the documentation's note too! http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html )